# Finding the position of a face using emgucv (c#)

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-detection

I have got my code to be able to detect a face and then put a box around where it finds a face but I am looking to get the position of the box that it puts. 
Any position would be great to get as I can adjust other code for a particular position.

How may I be able to get the position from this?

Many Thanks

```
 private void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            Image<Bgr, byte> grayImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);
            Rectangle[] rectangles = cascadeClassifier1.DetectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.2, 1);
            foreach (Rectangle rectangle in rectangles)
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
                    {
                        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
                    }
                }
            }
            plc.Image = bitmap;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the top left x and y coordinate of the rectangle, and the width and height.

```
//Get the top left cord
int rectX = rectangle.X;
int rectY = rectangle.Y;

//Get the width and height of the rectangle
int rectWidth = rectangle.Width;
int rectHeight = rectangle.Height;
```

Using those above values, you can find the cords of the other three points of the rectangle.

```
//The top right cord
int topRightX = rectX + rectWidth;
int topRightY = rectY;

//The bottom left cord
int bottomX = rectX;
int bottomY = rectY + rectHeight;

//The bottom right cord
int bottomRightX = rectX + rectWidth;
int bottomRightY = rectY + rectHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on how to get the points. But, I don't understand why for the bottom points i need to add the rectHeight. If rectY is the height of the top part of the rectangle, wouldn't you subtract the height to get the bottom of the rectangle?

Comment: In Opencv and Emgucv, pixel and coordinate locations are used on the IV quadrant in a coordinate system, but the Y values are always positive. Both libraries use the top-left coordinate as their reference point, and as you go from the top of the image to the bottom of the image, you are increasing your Y coordinate. I know it sounds a bit weird, but like I said earlier, I just think of it as using the IV quadrant, but with all values being positive.